# compilation Error with NDK using c++static

Tags: android, c++11, android-ndk, webrtc

I am compiling my project with `ndk` and I want to use `c++_static` to build my project. For this I am using-

```
APP_STL := c++_static
```

And

```
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11 -pthread -frtti  -Wno-format-extra-args -Wno-format-zero-length -Wdeprecated-declarations -fno-builtin-cos -fno-builtin-sin -fno-builtin-cosf -fno-builtin-sinf -fexceptionsin
```

in my `Application.mk`

But this is giving me error :

```
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:313:9: error: '::signbit' has not been declared
 using ::signbit;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:314:9: error: '::fpclassify' has not been declared
 using ::fpclassify;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:315:9: error: '::isfinite' has not been declared
 using ::isfinite;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:316:9: error: '::isinf' has not been declared
 using ::isinf;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:318:9: error: '::isnormal' has not been declared
 using ::isnormal;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:319:9: error: '::isgreater' has not been declared
 using ::isgreater;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:320:9: error: '::isgreaterequal' has not been declared
 using ::isgreaterequal;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:321:9: error: '::isless' has not been declared
 using ::isless;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:322:9: error: '::islessequal' has not been declared
 using ::islessequal;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:323:9: error: '::islessgreater' has not been declared
 using ::islessgreater;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:324:9: error: '::isunordered' has not been declared
 using ::isunordered;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:325:9: error: '::isunordered' has not been declared
 using ::isunordered;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:327:9: error: '::float_t' has not been declared
 using ::float_t;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:328:9: error: '::double_t' has not been declared
 using ::double_t;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:485:9: error: '::acosl' has not been declared
 using ::acosl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:486:9: error: '::asinl' has not been declared
 using ::asinl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:487:9: error: '::atanl' has not been declared
 using ::atanl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:488:9: error: '::atan2l' has not been declared
 using ::atan2l;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:490:9: error: '::cosl' has not been declared
 using ::cosl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:491:9: error: '::coshl' has not been declared
 using ::coshl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:492:9: error: '::expl' has not been declared
 using ::expl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:495:9: error: '::fmodl' has not been declared
 using ::fmodl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:498:9: error: '::logl' has not been declared
 using ::logl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:499:9: error: '::log10l' has not been declared
 using ::log10l;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:500:9: error: '::modfl' has not been declared
 using ::modfl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:501:9: error: '::powl' has not been declared
 using ::powl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:502:9: error: '::sinl' has not been declared
 using ::sinl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:503:9: error: '::sinhl' has not been declared
 using ::sinhl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:504:9: error: '::sqrtl' has not been declared
 using ::sqrtl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:505:9: error: '::tanl' has not been declared
 using ::tanl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:508:9: error: '::tanhl' has not been declared
 using ::tanhl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:509:9: error: '::acoshl' has not been declared
 using ::acoshl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:510:9: error: '::asinhl' has not been declared
 using ::asinhl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:511:9: error: '::atanhl' has not been declared
 using ::atanhl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:512:9: error: '::cbrtl' has not been declared
 using ::cbrtl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:518:9: error: '::erfl' has not been declared
 using ::erfl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:519:9: error: '::erfcl' has not been declared
 using ::erfcl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:520:9: error: '::exp2l' has not been declared
 using ::exp2l;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:521:9: error: '::expm1l' has not been declared
 using ::expm1l;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:526:9: error: '::hypotl' has not been declared
 using ::hypotl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:528:9: error: '::lgammal' has not been declared
 using ::lgammal;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:529:9: error: '::llrintl' has not been declared
 using ::llrintl;
         ^
/Users/aagman/Desktop/Project/Android/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cmath:531:9: error: '::log1pl' has not been declared
 using ::log1pl;             ^
```

Please help me out with this problem. Earlier I built my project using gnustl_shared and it works fine, but because of some constraint I need to build my project using `c++ static` or `c++_shared`.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue when including `<complex>` using the LLVM libc++ STL. A 'solution' which worked for me was to comment out these particular lines in `ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/cmath`.

Comment: Which Ndk did you use, i am useing R-12b and I could not find the path you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

**It is unlikely something wrong with the std lib in NDK.**

I experienced the similar problem recently, had exact stack but with different NDK version (16b).
I was trying to compile folly with cmake.

Turns out I had "-I src/folly/folly" folder in the include paths and by some reason cmake didn't put the system includes first.

The compiler was looking for `<math>` and other system libraries in the folly folder.
As soon I removed this folder from the list of includes the problem was gone.

1. Look for the files which define the primitives used in cmath and then find the files with the same names in your path.
2. Remove not needed folders from includes
3. Make sure that system includes are first on the list.